# Server restart cause

Tags: linux

since few week I'm observing a strange behaviour of my linux box.
It randomly restarts without any evident cause.
messages, syslog and dmesg do not point to any direction.
Looking at bios (dmidecode) neither brings no news.
I also redirected kernel messages at grub level to a serial port, another pc is logging serial output. In spite I had already two reboots I didn't get any trace of the cause.

can a defective PSU cause such issue without leave any track?
can anybody sugest me any other way to investigate on this matter?

Comment: This server is composed by an Intel Atom D525 on an Intel D525MW mainboard with firmware version MWPNT10N.86A.0083.2011.0524.1600. There is the PCI slot populated with a Sangoma A200 card. Just one USB peripheral: a ps/2 to USB adapter. PSU is 150W

Comment: PSU might be the cause or memory, or few other options. Try to load it with some CPU-heavy or I/O heavy task. See if it would restart under load.

Comment: If the cause is memory, which I tested twice, shouldn't I find anything on kernel messages?

Comment: I want to apply your suggestion: heavy load on CPU and I/O. Could you please hint me how to do?

Comment: Anything. Computing `md5sum` of your filesystem or `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null` for instance. Just to see if higher load would cause a reboot.

Comment: I tried some test as your suggestion. I made all 4 hyper-thread cpus busy 100% for several minutes. I also made disk busy reading raw block device. But during this busy time no reboot happened. However during night system restarted by itself without leave any trace of failure in logs.

Comment: If it's a faulty capacitor in the PSU the frequency of restarts should gradualy increase with the time. Also do the restarts happen randomly during the day or close to specific time? Is the machine brand new?

Comment: Actually the machine is in service since more than one year. Restarts are pretty random, but I have the impression that close to the time of restarts, the system is more sensiteve to loads. I notice that when I check for logs shortly after a reboot system has tendencies to reboot.

Comment: "restart" or "hard power cycle"? is it actually going through a runlevel reboot gracefully, or simply a hard power off and power on?

Comment: At last I decided to replace PSU to see if my doubts make any sense. 24 hours later No reboot yet. it seems the cause might be the PSU after all. In the mean time I disassembled the old one and found two capacitor both with one pin not soldered. I wonder if the removed PSU malfunctioning can be associated to this defect....

Answer (score 2):

If there are no indication in the logs then it's hardware related, typically motherboard, memory, CPU. For memory the indicated read/write tests with 'dd' can be used, since that's fine you can look into CPU temperature (BIOS), otherwise it can be 'anywhere' in the motherboard. Another issue could be the power supply and incoming brown-outs/spikes.

Comment: Yea, I'll second this opinion. Almost certainly hardware, could be almost anything: faulty motherboard, etc.

Comment: As I wrote in my las post, I found evidences problem lays in faulty PSU, infact, After unassembled it, I notice it is a poorly assembled piece of hardware, with two capacitor poorly soldered. However just for my understanding, let's assume bad memory with some faulty locations. the worse it can happen is some memory fault, and shouldn't it be seen on kernel logs

Comment: The faulty PSU seems to be the most probable cause, but there still something I can not understand, and it is: why this problem appeared after months and not as soon as this server started to work?